# Color all tick labels in scientific notation

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to color the tick labels of my left vertical axis. However, the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot([1,5,10],[1,5,10])

ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_yscale('log')

ax.set_xlim([1e0,1e1])
ax.set_ylim([1e0,1e1])

ax.yaxis.label.set_color('b')
ax.spines['left'].set_edgecolor('b')
ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors='b')

plt.savefig('test.png')
plt.show()
```

fails to color all lables:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors='b', which='both')
```

where `both` corresponds to the major as well as the minor ticks.

**Output**

[image]